# Automating SVN to create build

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am new here and realize this may not sound very technical but, I have a website in one location and I use tortoise to update my working copy on my desktop between developers. However, when developers give me revision numbers, is there a way to enter these revisions into SVN and it provide me the paths and files that require to be updated? Or Am I able to enter the revisions numbers and have a script move these revisions to the server where my website is hosted? After I update my SVN I currently have to drag and drop individual files between my desktop and a server to push to production. This is very unreliable and unproductive.

Comment: svn has a commandline which you can use to get a snapshot based on a revision number

Comment: You **have to** provide more deep and technical description of your current workflow. Currently it allow *too many* different different interpretations

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/tortoisesvn-exporting-changed-files/ http://www.electrictoolbox.com/subversion-export-changed-files-cli-v2/